# Correlation vs Regression

Tags: regression, correlation

I am a physician and I'm always in doubt when I need to use a regression model. I have 92 samples and for each one I have the gene expression levels of 50,000 genes. I performed a correlation test comparing one gene of interest ('X") with all the other genes and found the 10 genes that best correlate with X.
Since correlation doesn't imply causation, what's the significance of my results? Do I need to build a regression model to believe that these genes are really associated? If so, what's the value of a correlation test as a first step in situations like this?

Comment: I was told that to establish a causal link between events you need to show the existence of a *mechanism* or *path* between them. E.g. some time ago a colleague of mine found a correlation between the activity of compounds on a kinase X and in a phenotypic assay Y. Was X responsible for the observed activity in Y? Based on the correlation alone you couldn't tell. However further literature evidence and ad-hoc laboratory assays strengthened the link between the two and confirmed that X was indeed causing the phenotypic activity.

Comment: thank you very much, @user6376297. So, returning to my most elementary doubt, when should I apply a regression model?

Comment: I'll have to let people with better statistics knowledge than myself answer that one. I can only say that as far as I am aware, regression is based on the assumption that a given model applies, and if you make your model very complicated you can probably fit anything, but it still does not prove causation. Causation is mechanistic in nature.

Comment: BTW, just occurred to me that you may be interested in looking at the work done by Dr. A. Lee (University of Cambridge, UK). He's been working extensively on the problem of disentangling correlation vs causation, using rather sophisticated methods. He presented his work at several conferences on machine learning and AI, and he applied his methodology on case studies relevant to the pharmaceutical industry. E.g. see this paper: https://www.pnas.org/content/116/9/3373 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a correlation test you measure the strength of association between two variables.
Association is the first step to assess causation.
Nevertheless, no statistical test can test causation.
What you can say it`s that your data show a certain correlation between 10 genes and your genes of interest ('X').

To assess causation you still need to address two issues:
1) order (which factor is the cause).
2) non-spuriousness correlation.

For these you need experiments and a good theory to be proved.

Comment: many thanks, Giulia. And what is the aim of a regression model in this context and in general?

Comment: The goal of regression is to create a mathematical model in order to predict your response variable (let`s say your gene X).

Fitting a regression model you can find for example that $X = a*X1 - b*X2$ (where $X1$ and $X2$ are two other genes) approximate quite well your data.

Answer (score 0):

In general, in a linear regression of the form $Y = X1 + X2 + ... + X_n$, the variable $Y$ is being predicted by a **linear** combination of the $n$ predictors. You can think of correlation as a simple regression of the form $Y = aX$, where if both $Y$ and $X$ are standardized, then $a$ is equal to the correlation coefficient between those variables.

In your case, if you were to fit a regression predicting your target gene $X$ by a combination of two or more of the other genes, then the implicit assumption is that the predictor genes work together in a linear fashion to predict changes to the target gene. Is that assumption valid for what you want to investigate? I am really not sure. You may want to track down a copy of *Statistical Methods in Bioinformatics: An Introduction* (2005) by Warren J. Ewens and Gregory R. Grant. They discuss DNA analysis in detail in the second half of the book.

You mentioned analyzing the correlations between your target gene and the other 50,000, and then selecting the *10 genes that best correlate with X*. I think it is crucial to examine the distribution of these associations. Are the correlations for these 10 candidate genes a lot higher than the rest? If that's the case, then you are probably on to something. But if there are tens, or maybe hundreds of other genes who are close, or very close to the top 10, then you can be pretty sure that if you were to run a similar analysis on new samples, which genes make it to the top 10 genes will be very likely to change.